How do I set the cookie policy within Electron.NET
I'm working on a Blazor Server app at work and we have been asked to create a desktop version. I have been trying to use Electron.NET, but I am running into issues when authenticating through Azure AD. I'm receiving the following error
stdout: fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN2V44AL6L5H", Request id "0HN2V44AL6L5H:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
       ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

If I remove the authentication service, it works.
It seems to be caused by the cookie "SameSite=None" since the secure cookie is not set to secure. How do I set the cookie policy to set change the SameSite policy or the security policy?
I have already tried adding the policy to the webapp within the main program,
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
});

// or 


app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
});

but this does not seem to do anything.
Electron.NET also doesn't let you to specify https or even use the web app running when app.Run() is called. It seems that it creates its own instance that uses the settings in the electron.manifest.json.

@Rukmini the issue the security is set to None, so explicitly setting the policy to None will not fix my issue. From what I have tested, Electron does not let you change the cookie policy through the builder or the app.
Also, your response feels like a ChatGPT response.
